# Tlist обновление без очистки

Tags: delphi

Имеется 2 StringList'а, задача, первый - обновляется раз в сек. Задача обновлять второй(приводить к виду первого) не(!!!) очищая его. т.е. только добавить недостающие элементы и удалить те которых уже нет в первом. Самое оптимальное что пришло в голову 2 цикла с проверкой есть ли элемент в списке. что очень неоптимально(как мне кажется). 
Получается L*N*2 интераций, где L и N кол-во элементов листов.

Comment: [Тут](http://hashcode.ru/questions/125419/delphi-максимально-быстрый-алгоритм-сравнения-2х-строк) похожая задача решалась, т.е. быстро искать значения в списках. THashedStringList неплох.

Comment: Именнто Tlist класс, т.к. элементы конечного списка - комбо бокс)

Comment: Tlist - абстрактный класс, от которого наследуется, например, TStringList, поэтому, говорите про TStringList, а не про абстракцию.

Comment: А второй список случайно не TListView (или аналоги - TListBox, ...) и используется для отображения?

Comment: TList абстрактный? разве? а как насчет такого использования класса 
i:integer; t:TList; i=10; t.add(@I); i:=t[0]; нет) второй случайно Tstrings(допилить до StringList дело минуты), а первый - случайно дин массив, который можно загнать куда угодно(в т.ч. в стринг лист, ибо переписать его заполнение дело минуты).

Comment: @ToRcH565 Допилите лучше THashedStringList (повторяюсь, ага) или сразу TObjectBucketList, будет более универсально... Хотя при макс 300 элементах и обычный TList.IndexOf будет работать нормально. Вообще откуда желание оптимизировать такую мелочь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Количество итераций можно уменьшить до L+N используя такой код

```
    var
i:integer;
sl1, sl2: TstringLIst
begin
for I := 0 to sl1.Count-1 do if sl2.IndexOf(sl1.Strings[i])=-1 then  sl2.Add(sl1.Strings[i]);
for I := sl2.Count downto 0    do if sl1.IndexOf(sl2.Strings[i])=-1 then  sl2.Delete(i);
```

Первым циклом мы проверяем есть запись с первого листа во втором и если нет то добавляем, а вторым цыклом мы чистим второй лист от тех зписей которых нет в первом листе.

Comment: Если списки не сортированные, то это решение описанное в вопросе. И будет оно работать O(L*N), как и предполагалось.

Comment: Как предполагал автор, известно только ему одному, но у меня сложилось впечатление что он сам хотел писать циклы.
Посмотрев реализацию indexOf я понял что действительно алгоритм решения мой и автора одинаков, но мой по коду меньше :)

Comment: Уже хотел добавить что у вас интераций ровно L*N*2))

Comment: Еще вопрос, если кто сталкивался, не будет ли интераций меньше если реализовать ф-ию разности массивов(аля разность set) и проводить манипуляции именно с разницей первого и второго массива.(не понимаю абсолютно алгоритма разности set)/

Comment: **Set** имеет ограничение в 256 элементов.
Сомневаюсь что вам этого хватит.

а о каком размере списков идет речь?

Comment: думаю этого может хватить(хотя по хорошему 300 элементов, но можно сделать остальные невидимыми) и речь идет о том как же там реализована разность а не о ограничениях типа..

Answer (score -1):

А почему не:

```
StringList2.Assign(StringList1)
```

ну если нужно соблюдать порядок тогда:

```
procedure UpdateList(SourceList, UpdList: TStringList);
var
  S: string;
begin
  UpdList.BeginUpdate;    
  for S in UpdList do 
    if SourceList.IndexOf(S) = -1 then
      UpdList.Delete(UdpList.IndexOf(S));

  for S in SourceList do
    if UpdList.IndexOf(S) = -1 then
      UpdList.Add(S);
  UpdList.EndUpdate;    
end;
```

если списки огромны и скорость важна тогда:

```
procedure UpdateList(SourceList, UpdList: TStringList);
var
  I: Integer;
  S: string;
  TmpSrcList: TStringList;
  TmpUpdList: TStringList;
begin
  UpdList.BeginUpdate;
  TmpSrcList := TStringList.Create;
  TmpUpdList := TStringList.Create;
  try 
    I := 0;
    TmpSrcList.Assign(SourceList);
    TmpSrcList.Sort;  // для бинарного поиска

    for S in UpdList do
      if TmpSrcList.IndexOf(S) <> -1 then
        TmpUpdList.Add(S);

    UpdList.Assign(TmpUpdList);
    TmpUpdList.Sort;

    for S in SourceList do
      if TmpUpdList.IndexOf(S) = -1 then
        UpdList.Add(S);

  finally
    TmpSrcList.Free;
    TmpUpdList.Free;
    UpdList.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

ComboBox??
Этот код у мене не мигает:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  I, J: Integer;
  Tmp: string;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate;  // мешаем список
  for I := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count -1 do
  begin
    Tmp := Memo1.Lines[I];
    J := Random(Memo1.Lines.Count -1);
    Memo1.Lines[I] := Memo1.Lines[J];
    Memo1.Lines[J] := Tmp;
  end;
  Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;

  ComboBox1.Items.Assign(Memo1.Lines);  // и переносим в ComboBox
end;
```

Comment: Вы задачу читали?
Если читали то скажите какой из трех вариантов соответствует решению её?

Comment: Вторая функа эквивалентна коду savro:


var
i:integer;
sl1, sl2: TstringLIst
begin
for I := 0 to sl1.Count-1 do if sl2.IndexOf(sl1.Strings[i])=-1 then  sl2.Add(sl1.Strings[i]);
for I := sl2.Count downto 0    do if sl1.IndexOf(sl2.Strings[i])=-1 then  sl2.Delete(i);


а третья с оптимизацией. Хотя не понимаю почему нельзя просто скопировать первый список. Можете объяснить вашу задачу?

Comment: Попробуйте сделать на открытом списке комбо бокса, очищать и заполнать раз 5 в секунду, как думаете, пользователю понравиться невозможность выбрать элемент, и постоянное дрожание списка.

Comment: и пы.сы   for I := 0 to MyClass.MySubClass.Count-1 do
    ComboBox3.Items.Add(MyClass.MySubClass.MyDynArr[i].Name,@MyClass.MySubClass.MyDynArr[i]);

Comment: т. е. "дрожит"? невозможно по нему попасть или мигает?

Comment: Попробуйте пролистать список из 100+ записей, который несколько раз в секунду очищается, и возвращает скрол в начало.